# Go to frame after HTML5 video playback end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, safari

I have a simple HTML page on which I've set up a fullscreen background video (no loop) using the **Vide** [plugin](http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/).

Now it works wonders, however I want the video to "freeze" on its last frame to display a logo I've included at the end of the video. 
It naturally does in all browsers except for Safari. If, after the video ends, I happen to go to another tab and come back, safari switches to displaying a random frame in the video as "poster", for no apparent reason.

To avoid this, I thought I could add a script to make the video go to somewhere in the last frames after it has ended, and I've found the following tip:

```
v.addEventListener("ended", function(){
this.currentTime = 0;
});
```

I've tried incorporating into my page but it's not working and I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction?

Vide says the following:

```
// Get instance of the plugin
var instance = $('#yourElement').data('vide');

// Get video element of the background. Do what you want.
instance.getVideoObject();
```

And I've come up with this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="video" data-vide-bg="video/video" data-vide-options="loop: false, muted: true, position: 50% 50%">
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var video = $('#video').data('vide');

    video.getVideoObject().addEventListener("ended", function() { 
       this.currentTime = 1; 
    });
</script>
```

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

1. On the `ended` event get the `.duration` of the video
2. Next set `.currentTime` to `.duration`
3. Then `.pause()`

In order to get the real video tag from the Vide plugin replace:

> ```
> var vid1 = document.getElementById('vid1')
> ```

with:

> ```
> var vid1 = document.querySelector('video');
> ```

in the demo. Doing so should be able to directly control the video **unless** the plugin uses an `<iframe>` or doesn't use a `<video>` tag at all. To verify do the following when you play the video:

1. Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Edge <kbd>F12</kbd> or Safari <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
2. Select the "Element" (or equivalent i.e. first tab) tab
3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
4. Search for the `<video>` tag by finding the plugin id hook. (i.e. the id of the element that uses the plugin.)
5. There should be a `<video>` tag, an `<iframe>`, or maybe `<object>` within that element that the plugin hooks into.
6. If it's a `<video>` you're in business, the other 2 tags are highly unlikely (especially an `<iframe>` since this is a background video.)

### Demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="vid1" class="vid" src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" controls></video>
  <script>
    var vid1 = document.getElementById('vid1');
    vid1.addEventListener('ended', captureFrame);

    function captureFrame(e) {
      var lastFrame = this.duration;
      this.currentTime = lastFrame;
      this.pause();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @zer00ne, thank you for taking the time to help me with this! I checked and the plugin does use a <video> tag, so that's good news. I understand your script but when I try it, console gives me the following error:  "var vid1 = document.querySelector('video'); **is not an object (evaluating 'vid1.addEventListener')**".

Comment: That's a strange error message...is that `<video>` tag inside an `<iframe>`? If you're not used to debugging with the console it's easy to not see it. Do a search on `<iframe` (verbatim) and if there are any open them up to see if any of them lead to the `<video>` tag. If you do find the `<video>` tag, then there's some extra code and certain things to consider. I'll await for your reply, sir.

Comment: @Meditor One more thing I need to know is where did you place the code on the page. It should be before the `</body>` end tag and should be the last lines of JS as well.